# How to exclude a user from an applied password policy

Tags: windows, domain, group-policy, password, exclude

I have received a requirement that a single user needs to be excluded from the company's password policy (the CEO if you ask).

as such, I have tried the following with no success.

1. I have copied the default domain password settings to a new object.
2. I have enabled that new opbject to auhtenticated users.
3. In the domain Password delegation settings, I have added the specific user, and in the: Apply check box - I set it to Deny  [image]
   *should I also set the Deny Read option?

I can see that when the user logs in, gpresult shows that the Domain Password GP is applied, however, he still gets the same restrictions as the rest of the domain.

Q: What am I doing wrong?
- : How can I exclude a user from a domain policy?

Much appreciate

Answer (score 8):

Windows Active Directory has two different styles of Password Policy:

- One you set in Default Domain Policy (or another GPO linked to the domain root-object) that applies to everything without exception (2000-2008r2)
- A [Fine Grained Password Policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770394%28WS.10%29.aspx) that allows you to set different policies to different groups complete with exceptions (2008-2008r2)

The first kind is rather difficult to work with because of the 'no exceptions' item. Special-snowflake users, like yours, can't be accommodated, and neither can certain critical utility users (like the user all the web-apps use for LDAP-binds). This is why Fine Grained Password Policies were born.

FGPG are *not* GPO based, they're applied through a different mechanism entirely. However, you do need to be at the Server 2008 functional-level to even use them at all. They can allow you to set a single password policy for all users except for a special group, and set a completely different policy for that one group. Or a different policy for each one of those special users. It even has a mechanism to handle policy overlaps to determine which policy will win when more than one could apply.

The Server 2000 style of applies-to-everyone password polciy can be hard to understand. It is set in one and only one place, a GPO linked to the domain root object. The settings were visible in any GPO, but they don't do anything when set in policies that are not linked to root.

Comment: thanks. according to you: 1. as I work with 2k3 - this is not possible.  2. the password policy now ARE NOT ENFORCED?  as they are not in the Default Domain Policy?  Is this correct?

Comment: @Saariko Turns out I was wrong (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc875814.aspx). The password settings only apply *to a GPO linked to the root of the domain*.